# Does Tuvok ever outwardly show emotions?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Unlike Spock, Tuvok appears to be truly stoic, never showing any outward emotion. Though I'm not a Voyager expert and so I'm wondering if this is truly the case. Instances where Tuvok is being controlled by an alien, or is being represented by a hologram, etc., do not count. Nor does the "Living Witness" Tuvok count, nor Tuvok after he melds with the Maquis lunatic ("Meld").

I think that it can be argued that Tuvok most certainly shows frustration at times, but I'm looking mainly for anger, happiness, sadness, excitement, and so on.

Comment: Does [Riddles](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Riddles_(episode)) count? How about future-Tuvok when he's losing his mind? Or are you looking for a fully healthy and mentally intact Tuvok?

Comment: I assume you also mean outside of Pon Farr.  What about Flashback s3e02?

Answer (score 9):

In the final Voyager episode "Endgame", Tuvok was visibly agitated over Janeway's disappearance.  He raised his voice in his confusion and paced uncontrollably.  His lack of discipline was no doubt due to the progression of his degenerative neurological condition.  Other than this, there were no emotional outbursts that I'm aware of.  Even in "Cold Fire", when Kes boiled him alive, he didn't scream.   And after that horrible experience, he was stoic and willing to continue to instruct Kes in the use of her psi abilities.